# bootstrap progress bar doesn't render inside react component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs

A simple bootstrap progress bar that works inside my HTML code.

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
     <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Wouldn't render properly in my React component. The progress color is absent.

```
var DreamLane = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
   <div className="progress">
       <div className="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" styles="width:70%">
      <span className="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
      </div>
   </div>

   }
});
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have `style` property not `styles` and `style` prop needs mapping from style properties to values, not a string. So this would work:

```jsx
<div className='progress'>
  <div className='progress-bar'
       role='progressbar'
       aria-valuenow='70'
       aria-valuemin='0'
       aria-valuemax='100'
       style={{width: '70%'}}>
    <span className='sr-only'>70% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked. But, earlier, using style was throwing me errors.
What's with the two curly braces, around width?

Comment: it is just an object literal inlined in the prop value. you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/6f44f6049edfd7a66448ac50cd4415f6c26fd4b5/docs/tips/19--dangerouslySetInnerHTML.md)

Answer (score 12):

I just had to do it today. this worked for me.

```
<div className='progress'>
  <div className='progress-bar'
       role='progressbar'
       aria-valuenow={70}
       aria-valuemin={0}
       aria-valuemax={10}
       style={{width: '70%'}}>
    <span className='sr-only'>70% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`aria-valuemin`, `aria-valuemin` and  `aria-valuemax` expects a number, not a string